# How to take different templates as an input based on condition using ngTemplateOutlet in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have running Angular 12 application and I want to achieve a scenario where I want to display different html templates without creating components inside parent component using ngTemplateOutlet. All the different templates is a separate html files

**parent.component.html**

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="templatePath"> 

<ng-template #test1></ng-template> // displays the content of test1.html
<ng-template #test2></ng-template> //  displays the content of test2.html
```

templatePath is basically path of the html template which will come as an input property.

**parent.component.ts**

```
templatePath = './test1.html'; // not sure how to fetch the html template, so added this
```

**test1.html**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

This is just a html template file. I don't want to use component for this

**test2.html**

```
<h1>Welcome</h1>
```

This is just a html template file. I don't want to use component for this

I am not sure whether ngTemplateOutlet is the right way to achieve the above scenario. Please suggest what can be used in Angular to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and use your own myVar variable:

```
<ng-container *ngIf=“myVar === 1; then test1 else test2”></ng-container>
<ng-template #test1></ng-template> // displays the content of test1.html
<ng-template #test2></ng-template> //  displays the content of test2.html
```

Comment: How do I fetch the test1.html content in parent.component.ts and use that to display..?

Comment: add its tag between  <ng-template #test1> <app-my-custom-component></my-custom-component> </ng-template >

Comment: I don't want to create any custom component. I just want to fetch html content and display that

Comment: You could use a separate component  for each template for security purpose.I didn't  any angular technique could do what You need to apply.